# What is wrong with following bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I wrote following line in my script , but it not assigning any value to variable a

```
a= grep -n mark /etc/samba/smb.conf |cut -d: f1
```

I aspect line number where mark string present in smb.conf in variable a. But value of variable is null. What may be the issue

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two things:

1. There can be no spaces between name of the variable, the `=` signal and the value of the variable
2. If you want to put the results of a command or series of commands on a variable, you must enclose it on `$(command)` or old style backticks. Both lines below are correct and do the same thing:

   ```
   a=`commands`
   a=$(commands)
   ```

So your line must be

```
a=$(grep -n mark /etc/samba/smb.conf |cut -d: f1)
```

There are some differences on how to concatenate the use of backticks or new style `$()`, check [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215889/whats-the-difference-between-result-ls-l-or-result-ls-l) to see a good response.

Comment: +1. I recommend putting the delimiter character in single quotes, too: `-d':'`. It's not needed here, but it's a good habit to have.

Answer (score 2):

```
a=`grep -n mark /etc/samba/smb.conf |cut -d: -f1`
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead

`a=$(grep -n mark /etc/samba/smb.conf |cut -d: f1)`

Or instead of the $() you could use backticks (which here turn on the nice code look)

Answer (score 1):

Should be a=`$( ... )` or

```
a=` … `
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe by trying to use cut like this:

```
a=`grep -n mark /etc/samba/smb.conf |cut -d: -f1`
```